# Import Bootstrap in Astro

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, integration, bootstrap-5, astrojs

I am currently working on Astro (astro.build) and would like to use it with the latest Bootstrap version.

**Does anyone know about Astro and can please explain to me how to properly integrate Bootstrap?**

Didn't find anything on the internet or here in the forum, at least there wasn't a clear answer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: The short answer is that you'd either add resources as normal (say via CDN) or import from a repository (such as NPM). AstroJS seems somewhat apathetic about all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options here:

### CDN

In your index.astro file, you can add both Bootstrap latest CSS and JS in the header and body sections respectively like so

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### npm

You can install Bootstrap via NPM like so

```bash
npm install bootstrap@latest
```

And require it in your `index.astro` file within the frontmatter fences

You can check out this starter template for more ideas on usage
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-npm-starter

Answer (score 5):

For npm/yarn:

`index.astro`

```
---
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import bootstrap from "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js?url";
---
<html>
<script src={bootstrap}></script>
<!-- Your page here -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting Typescript errors `<script> uses an expression for the src attribute and will be ignored.` and switched to Astro's [suggested CSS](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#import-a-stylesheet-from-an-npm-package) and [JS implementation](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/#script-processing) using `import`.

```bash
# install via npm
npm install bootstrap@latest
```

and then use `import` in your `.astro` file

```
---
// Astro will bundle and optimize this automatically
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
---

<html>
  <!-- Your page here -->
</html>

<script>
  // Astro will bundle and process this automatically
  import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'
</script>
```